# Not able to scan datetime format barcode using zxing barcode scanner

Tags: zxing, barcode-scanner, zxing-js

I integrated **ZXING** barcode scanner into my project but its not working for datetime format `2021-05-19 12:25:09`

I tried to scan using https://zxing-js.github.io/ngx-scanner and enable all the format but no luck.

In my codebase after scanning I am getting random numeric value as result.

I used the following barcode format in my code

````
  BarcodeFormat.CODE_128, BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX, BarcodeFormat.EAN_8, BarcodeFormat.EAN_13,
  BarcodeFormat.ITF, BarcodeFormat.MAXICODE, BarcodeFormat.PDF_417, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, BarcodeFormat.RSS_14,
  BarcodeFormat.RSS_EXPANDED, BarcodeFormat.UPC_A, BarcodeFormat.UPC_E, BarcodeFormat.UPC_EAN_EXTENSION]```
````

Comment: It will be easier to get advice and answers if you present the barcode image you created and scanned. By the way, what kind of barcode do you create? Isn't it necessary to read only that type of barcode?

Comment: @kunif FYI https://barcode.tec-it.com/en/Code128?data=2021-05-19+12%3A25%3A09&multiplebarcodes=false&translate-esc=true&unit=Fit&dpi=96&imagetype=Gif&rotation=0&color=%23000000&bgcolor=%23ffffff&codepage=Default&qunit=Mm&quiet=0&hidehrt=False

Comment: It's better to present the image itself in the question article, rather than a link to an external service. For example, have you tried reading the barcode with a hardware scanner? Was there a difference between the results and the ZXING scan? It's a good idea to check these things step by step.

Comment: By the way, the barcode introduced in the link notified the appropriate character string when read by a hardware scanner (Honeywell Xenon 1900G) in SerialPort mode. There seems to be no problem with barcodes. Please add what the details of the datetime format not working with ZXING are. Are you expecting to be notified of something else that isn't a string?

Comment: @kunif I am trying to create **Code 128** format barcode (i.e. datetime) and trying to scan in angular web application using my mobile

Comment: What is the reason for not working in datetime format? Is the barcode data not notified? Or does it mean that the notified data was not in the desired format? In that case, please add what the notified data was and which function determined that it was not in the desired format. Isn't the problem with a function that is determined to be not in the desired format? For example, in Code128, it is common to include the application identifier in the data, but isn't it judged to be invalid because it is not attached?